# Extra pads on CAD footprint

Tags: connector, footprint, cad

A Phoenix 2 pin connector I am using, shown here:
https://app.ultralibrarian.com/details/eb577c4a-1e49-11e9-ab3a-0a3560a4cccc/Phoenix-Contact/1725656

has 2 pins and 2 mounting legs. The std view footprint shows 5 pads and the detailed view shows 6 pads. What do the additional pads represent?

Answer (score 0):

The Phoenix Contact 1725656 does has 4 bottom surface pins, but 2 of them are plastic locating pins (located nearer the edge), the metal signal pins are 1 and 2 (located near the center). The red circle (in your link) is just a pin 1 reference mark.

The dimensioned PCB pattern can be found [here](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/pcb-terminal-block-mpt-05-2-254-1725656).

You can also see a 3D rotatable view [here](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-us/products/printed-circuit-board-terminal-mpt-05-2-254-1725656).

[image]

```
     [Dimensions in mm]
```

[image]

(Above pictures from Phoenix Contact GmbH & Co. KG, at:
https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/pcb-terminal-block-mpt-05-2-254-1725656

.

Answer (score 0):

The extra pads are probably pin-1 indicators. The red one is within the outline so is either on a bottom silk layer or on a mechanical assembly layer. Tne black one is outside the outline so could be a top silk layer. You can download it o the PCB tool to have a look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered their purpose by importing into PCB and  turning off layers.

The (NOW) three in question were:

Pin 1 indicator: Frontside silkscreen
Pin 1 indicator: Backside silkscreen
Pin 1 indicator: Fronside fab

Thankd for both answers. They were equally helpful.